# Adding a relationship to an index in neo4jclient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

This might be real newbie question but please bear with me as I am new. I looked at this code sample in documentation.

```
 graphClient
    .Cypher
    .Start(new {
        n1 = "custom",
        n2 = nodeRef,
        n3 = Node.ByIndexLookup("indexName", "property", "value"),
        n4 = Node.ByIndexQuery("indexName", "query"),
        r1 = relRef,
        moreRels = new[] { relRef, relRef2 },
        r2 = Relationship.ByIndexLookup("indexName", "property", "value"),
        r3 = Relationship.ByIndexQuery("indexName", "query"),
        all = All.Nodes
    });
```

In the example above I would like to get a relationship by IndexLookup. So I created a Relationship Index

```
 _graphClient.CreateIndex("item_relationship_idx", new IndexConfiguration
            {
                Provider = IndexProvider.lucene,
                Type = IndexType.exact
            },
                 IndexFor.Relationship);
```

Question - How do I get a relationship created by _graphClient.CreateRelationship into an index. Most of the samples provided just show getting NodeReference into an Index. I am sure I am missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to Neo4jClient 1.0.0.568 or above and you'll find the (new) support for relationship indexing, consistent with how node indexing works.

(You should also look at Neo4j 2.0 and try and use the new indexing infrastructure though. No point writing new code against old approaches.)

Comment: Thanks Tatham. It works. Question - Can I use Neo4jClient 1.0.0.568 with Neo4j 2.0 ? I have my Neo4j DB hosted in the Azure so I am not quite sure how easy it will be to upgrade. I am really new to this and just got things to work.

Comment: Meanwhile, when I use Cypher query with Neo4jclient to return  relationship reference [part of code here..Cypher.Start(r2 = Relationship.ByIndexLookup("indexName", "property", "value")..Return<Relationship<Item>>("r2");] I get following error "Neo4jClient encountered an exception while deserializing the response from the server. This is likely a bug in Neo4jClient." Is there an example that shows returning relationship reference?

Comment: Also, I did install the 2.0 on the local machine. I need to explore if I can take advantage of the indexing infrastructure as you have recommended. All I need to do is specify "weight" in a relationship between two nodes and hence storing this in index for fast retrieval. I need to be able to change the "weight" depending on the algorithm. May be there is a simpler way to do it. Any tips will be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: For new questions (eg compatibility), please raise a new question.

Comment: For issues, please read the rest of the exception text that tells you to go to https://bitbucket.org/readify/neo4jclient/issues/new

Comment: @TathamOddie Got it. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

> Update to Neo4jClient 1.0.0.568 or above and you'll find the (new) support for relationship indexing, consistent with how node indexing works.

Does that mean I can use the Create method or do I still need the CreateRelationship method? I have Neo4jClient 1.0.0.590 but I don't find it that obvious.