# Adding relationship to index with Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4jclient

What's the syntax to add a relationship to an already created relationship index in the Neo4jClient?

I've found the following post ([Adding a relationship to an index in neo4jclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369345/adding-a-relationship-to-an-index-in-neo4jclient/18224368#18224368)) but it only says that the syntax is similar to that of nodes but the CreateRelationship method does not have a signature that supports inserting a relationship to the index.

Any help to a Neo4jClient noob would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the ReIndex command:

```
if(!GraphClient.CheckIndexExists("relatedto", IndexFor.Relationship))
    GraphClient.CreateIndex("relatedto", ExactIndex, IndexFor.Relationship);

var simple1 = new Simple {Value = "simple_1"};
var simple2 = new Simple { Value = "simple_2" };

var s1Ref = GraphClient.Create(simple1);
var s2Ref = GraphClient.Create(simple2);

var relationship = new RelatedTo(s2Ref){RelationshipValue = "indexed_" + s1Ref.Id};

var relRef = GraphClient.CreateRelationship(s1Ref, relationship);

//Adding to the index
GraphClient.ReIndex(relRef, new []{new IndexEntry("relatedto"){{"value", relationship.RelationshipValue}}});

Console.WriteLine("Use this in N4J Data Browser: rel:index:relatedto:value:{0}", relationship.RelationshipValue);
```